# Cocoa JSON - Check whether array or dictionary

Tags: cocoa, json

I am using the Cocoa JSON framework ( http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/ ) to communicate with an API.

The problem is that the API returns a dictionary if there is an error but returns an array of the results if it works.

Is there a good way to detect if the JSONValue is an array or a dictionary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `isKindOfClass:` to test whether the object is an instance of NSDictionary or of any subclass thereof.

In most circumstances, you would be better served by a `respondsToSelector:` check, but this is one case where you really are better off testing its class membership.

Of course, you can test whether it's an array instead of whether it's a dictionary; as long as the API you're using only returns an array or dictionary, the effect is the same.

For true robustness, test *both* array and dictionary membership, and throw an exception or present an error if the object is neither.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to check length property.

```
if (jsonObj.length) {
   //doSomeWork
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
if ([YourData isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Array format found");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Dictionary format found");
}
```